# When do Windows Store app staged updates get applied?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

We recently updated our app, and it's already been in the store (and accessible) with the new version for a few days now. We have many users who have not yet updated, including users who have updates set to automatic.

Is there some trigger or maintenance that is done at some point which applies the updates? Is there any way to know that it has not yet been done so that we can notify our users? If they want the update as soon as it's available (or within a reasonable time afterwards), are they forced to update the app manually via the store? Is there a setting somewhere for how often it applies updates?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the deal. I published a third release for my app. As soon as microsoft emailed me that my third release is in the store I got in and checked it out. It was there. I downloaded it. I did the same on my brothers laptop. 
This version of my app was supposed to reduce some bugs that were noted from a friend of mine. So when the version was live I told him to download the update. So he did. Got in the store searched to update the update app but the store told him that he had the latest version. He checked the version of his app and it was version behind.

Conclusion: When an update is live in the store even after a couple of days it's not live for everyone

Comment: This is the conclusion we have reached as well. Do you know if there's a way to simply notify the user? And/or a simple way for the app/user to expedite the update (without too much work from the user)? I believe they can go to the store, open the "App Updates" settings and do it manually, but that's a problem because nobody is willing to do that (which is why the auto-updates in the first place!)

Comment: Honestly I do now know. I notify my users using my facebook account that a new version is up. I always in the changelist add that it fixes some bugs to erge them to download it

Comment: @NateDiamond another way is to try to make the old version obsolete. For example my app downloads some stuff from the net on a location I set up. I try to change in my source code the location for the new version and make the data from the last version only include a message that reads "Please upload to the latest version"